# Google-Apps-Script Trigger for Google-Sheets provides incorrect answer compared to menu or manual executed script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, menu, execution

Does anyone know why Google Apps Script `Triggers` would provide different answers from the same script executed from a `menu`?  The code should only execute `doSomething()` on weekdays, between 12:50 & 1:00 PM, on non-holiday days when `run = true`.

My function...

```
function functionTester(test) {
  let now = new Date();
  let timeNow = (now.getHours() * 100) + now.getMinutes();
  let run = true;
  test = test || false;
  run = !test ? 
    ((now.getDay() == 6 || now.getDay() == 0 || timeNow < 1250 || timeNow > 1300 || Holiday(now)) ?
    false : true) : true;   // After hours, Weekend, Holiday

Logger.log("Run = "+run+"\r\n1 : "+(now.getDay() == 6)+"\r\n2 : "+(now.getDay() == 0)+"\r\n3 : "+(timeNow < 1250)+"\r\n4 : "+(timeNow > 1300)+"\r\n5 : "+Holiday(now));

  if (!run) { return };
  doSomething();
};
```

As expected, `run = false` because condition 3 = true when manually executed, which is the intended output...

```
Run = false
1 : false
2 : false
3 : true
4 : false
5 : false
```

But when I run this with a `trigger` i get the following...

```
Run = true
1 : false
2 : false
3 : true
4 : false
5 : false
```

`Run` is now `true` even though condition 3 is true.

Any ideas?

Comment: Define `doSomething`.........

Comment: doSomething() is just a generic function call to execute `function doSomething(){...}` if run = true.  For my example, run should be false, yet when executed with the automated trigger, it produces `true`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: yes but this function looks like it returns the wrong  result so edit your question to include the definition of that function. Make easier for the community to help you if you want to get helped.

Comment: But anyway, if you don't want to get helped here is an assumption that might help you. I suspect somewhere in your code you get the active sheet. But the active sheet does not work well with time triggers. You should define the sheet by its name. Like I said, this is an assumption because if we don't see the full code or a minimal reproducible example of the issue we can only assume...

Comment: The main function's (`functionTester(){...}`) goal is to determine whether or not to run `doSomething()`, but the google trigger always executes `doSomething()` when it is not supposed to.  I'm trying to determine why the main function sets `run = true` when executed by the trigger.  `doSomething()` is secondary and has no influence on the main function.

Comment: Could the google trigger have difficulty with nested ternary operators to set run to false on line 6?

Comment: I guess you meant to say: "`Run` is now `true` even though condition 3 is `true`"? Also, when is the trigger running? My guess is that the `test` parameter is somehow `true` (becoming `true` here too: `test = test || false;`), which makes `run` to be `true` even if one of the time conditions is not matched, but since time-triggered functions don't receive parameters, I'm unsure what's going on. Is this the exact code you're working on?

Comment: Yes,  this is the exact code.  However, I've rewritten the ternary conditions and checked ouotput from `test`.

Comment: Meant to say...    Yes,  this is the exact code.  However, I've rewritten the ternary conditions and checked the output for `test = [object Object]`. I'll force `test = false` for now.  The key was  "time-triggered functions don't receive parameters,"  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Iamblichus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10612011/iamblichus)! The key was...

> time-triggered functions don't receive parameters.

I deleted test from line 1, and forced `test = false` on line 5.  Otherwise, with code `test = test || false` on line 5, `test` is set to *`[object Object]`* ,which apparently makes **`test becomes truthy`**, and the other `conditions` are irrelevant. My updates always run when executed by a time trigger independent of the other conditions.

My newest code looks like this...

```
function functionTesterToo() {
  const now = new Date();
  const currentTime = (now.getHours() * 100) + now.getMinutes();
  const workDayStart = 1259, workDayEnd = 1300;
  const test = false;

  (test || (!(now.getDay() == 6 || now.getDay() == 0) && (currentTime > workDayStart && currentTime < workDayEnd) && !Holiday(now))) ?  Logger.log("Getting Updates!") : Logger.log("Skipped Updates!");

  Logger.log("test = "+test);
  Logger.log("Not a weekend? : "+!(now.getDay() == 6 || now.getDay() == 0));
  Logger.log("During work hours? : "+(currentTime > workDayStart && currentTime < workDayEnd));
  Logger.log("Not a holiday? : "+!Holiday(now));
};
```

After being executed from a time trigger the Logs now show this...

```
Mar 4, 2021, 9:50:08 AM   Info   Skipped Updates!
Mar 4, 2021, 9:50:08 AM   Info   test = false
Mar 4, 2021, 9:50:08 AM   Info   Not a weekend? : true
Mar 4, 2021, 9:50:08 AM   Info   During work hours? : false
Mar 4, 2021, 9:50:08 AM   Info   Not a holiday? : true
```